# Certificate verify failed due to recaptcha

Tags: python-3.x, recaptcha, flask-wtforms

I registered recaptcha for my WTForms, and This error **

> SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED pops up

when i submitted the form.

I registered recaptcha on google with `label = localhost` and `domains = localhost and 127.0.0.1`

When I submitted the form after verifying that I'm not a robot, I got redirected to the page with following error:

> urllib.error.URLError urllib.error.URLError: 
>   urlopen error [SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

If I set `app.config['TESTING']` to **True**, the form gets submitted just fine.

Here's what my app.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, RecaptchaField                                                                        
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField                                                                         
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, AnyOf                                                             

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisissecret!'
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = '6LdUxpsUAAAAAEKf7HmevAB9-ntHArEovS2pDmOP'
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = '6LdUxpsUAAAAACtXnVVOYTX1M9Hv83jkhzx4KxX1'
app.config['TESTING'] = False                                                                                           

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):                                                                                            
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(message='A username is required!'), Length(min=5, max=10, message='Must be between 5 and 10 characters')])                     
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(message='Password is required!'), AnyOf(values=['password', 'secret'])])                                                     
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()

@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():                                                                                       
        return '<h1>The username is {}. The password is {}.</h1>'.format(form.username.data, form.password.data)
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)                                                                     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In my form.html, I have included `{{ form.recaptcha }}` in the body section.

I expect that the form would submit just fine after the recaptcha validation.